# why c++ cannot infer templated nontype template argument?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-argument-deduction

Here is the code:

```
template <typename T, int P> struct _t_test_struct{
    T t;
    int p=P;
};
typedef _t_test_struct<float, 6> _test_struct6;

template <typename T, typename TP, TP P, template<typename, TP> class C>
void test1(C<T,P> &x){
    std::vector<T> _a;
    _a.resize(P);
    _a[0] = x.t;
    std::cout<<"typeid(P):"<<typeid(P).name()<<std::endl;

};

_test_struct6 _testp;
    _testp.t = 10;
    test1(_testp);
```

Why the compiler cannot determine the `TP` is `int`? I can only call it like `test1<float, int>(_testp)`.

Comment: Works here http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/40999945ca7f280f. What error are you getting?

Comment: @0x499602D2 - Works because you compile C++17. But the OP tagged this question C++11. I suppose that, if you compile C++11 or C++14, you get a compilation error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why the compiler cannot determine the `TP` is `int`? I can only call it like `test1<float, int>(_testp)`.

Cannot if you compile C++11 or C++14.

Can if you compile C++17, because C++17 improved template deduction rules.

Suggestion: give a look at the [corresponding page in CPP Reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction).

If I understand correctly, the problem is that until C++17 "Template type argument cannot be deduced from the type of a non-type template argument".

In your case,

```
template <typename T, typename TP, TP P, template<typename, TP> class C>
void test1(C<T,P> &x)
```

the `TP` type can't be deduced form `P`, a `TP` value (but works if you explicit `TP`, calling `test1<float, int>(_testp)`)

Starting from C++17, "When the value of the argument corresponding to a non-type template parameter P that is declared with a dependent type is deduced from an expression, the template parameters in the type of P are deduced from the type of the value.", so `TP` is deduced by `P`.